# twitter oauth php

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I am implementing a log-in system for my application based on twitter oAuth and I would like to get the email address and other basic info of tech user, is it possible to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to get basic info of user,Here is the list of all operations you can perform using twitter Rest API.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1

Answer (score 0):

[GET account/settings](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/account/settings)

Returns settings (including current trend, geo and sleep time information) for the authenticating user.

I cant find the email of logged user, but you can see other information.

Example:

```
{

    "always_use_https": true, 

    "discoverable_by_email": true, 

    "geo_enabled": true, 

    "language": "en", 

    "protected": false, 

    "screen_name": "theSeanCook", 

    "show_all_inline_media": false, 

    "sleep_time": {

        "enabled": false, 

        "end_time": null, 

        "start_time": null

    }, 

    "time_zone": {

        "name": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)", 

        "tzinfo_name": "America/Los_Angeles", 

        "utc_offset": -28800

    }, 

    "trend_location": [

        {

            "country": "United States", 

            "countryCode": "US", 

            "name": "Atlanta", 

            "parentid": 23424977, 

            "placeType": {

                "code": 7, 

                "name": "Town"

            }, 

            "url": "http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/place/2357024", 

            "woeid": 2357024

        }

    ], 

    "use_cookie_personalization": true

}
```

Comment: twitter api dont return email.. its confidential for them